# ZKSpringBoot HomePage Isnt Being Used

Tags: spring-boot, zk

I have a web application based on ZKSpringBoot. I am deploying as a war file in tomcat. If I hit the login page directly, I see the login and the application works fine. However I am having problems when I try the root URL "/". I look at the tomcat access logs and  see the access for URL "/". If I set a breakpoint in the FilterChainProxy, the request URL is "index.zul". So somewhere the request is being converted from "/" to "index.zul" I looked at the ZKSpringBoot code and cant find where that is happening.

- When I specify the zk homepage the property to zk.homepage=login and hit the root URL in the browser, I see in the filter chain that it is mapping it to /index.zul.
- I tried setting the property to zk.homepage=  and add a mapping to the Controller but see no difference.

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
  return "login";
  }
- I tried disabling both zk.homepage and request mapping and added a welcomepage but again no difference.

Has anyone else observed this issue or have a possible solution?